# Can't update from Node v0.10.46 on Mac

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I'm having problem's when trying to run my gulp command in the terminal. I've been trying to track down the issue and from what I can tell the issue is that I'm running an outdated version of node.

node -v tells me that I am on v0.10.46, but the Node install downloaded from the website says it's currently on v4.4.7.

The first issue I had was with es6 promises, but I managed to install the es6-polyfill which solved the issue.

Now gulp is throwing an error related to /node_modules/gulp-imagemin/index.js. Specifically the use of const variables. (const path = require('path')).

Based on this thread: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemin/issues/181#issuecomment-219303510 - this issue seems to be an outdated version of node, but no matter what I do it won't upgrade!

I've explored all possible avenues for upgrading Node - using npm, nvm, n, brew and even a local re-install, but everytime it seems to be installing an outdated version.

I've explored the possibility that I'm installing a 32bit version on a 64bit system, but that doesn't seem to be the issue either.

I have absolutely no idea how to progress fixing this issue. I'm trying to build a wordpress website, and no matter what theme I use this error comes back to haunt me!

Help!

EDIT:

Just to add.. in this image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD1cu.jpg) you can see the output of me trying to upgrade using N, and then following the David Walsh upgrading method.

Comment: It's unlikely that it's uninstalling the wrong version, and instead your environment is pointing to the older binary in a different location. What happens if you type `which node`?

Comment: have you tried using nvm https://github.com/creationix/nvm to manage your node versions? That might be the best route for you, as you can set the version you want to use

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried everything from uninstalling it by [this instructions](https://gist.github.com/TonyMtz/d75101d9bdf764c890ef) without any result. But maybe you have in your computer a management like **nvm** installed, just try this:

```
which node
```

And then if the respond of that is something like:

```
/Users/MYUSER/.nvm/v0.10.46/bin/node
```

That's the problem, so you can solve this by uninstalling nvm and then install **Node.js** normally or just keep using **nvm**